# Snowsql script not executed when run as here document from bash script

Tags: bash, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a bash script that contains something like this:

```
snowsql -a <account> -u <user> --authenticator externalbrowser -d <dbname> -o quiet=false <<-EOF
!source foo.sql
EOF
```

When I run it I don't see any of the output from the commands in foo.sql on the screen. It also appears that none of the SQL in foo.sql is executed (not reflected in state of database). Terminal output is:

```
* SnowSQL * v1.2.13
Type SQL statements or !help
Goodbye!
```

If I run foo.sql from an interactive Snowsql session the output from foo.sql is shown and the database is updated accordingly.

Why is foo.sql not executed when called in batch mode from the bash script?

Comment: Perhaps snowsql expects different options for batch mode? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#running-batch-scripts.  i.e. use -o output-file=FILENAME ... perhaps it might work -o output-file=-

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run it using -f parameter?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#running-while-connecting-f-connection-parameter

Comment: Using the -f parameter does work but I think it is a non-optimal workaround for my use case. I might have dozens of sql scripts to run and although multiple -f arguments appear to be supported it doesn't seem the most elegant way of issuing many sql scripts in one Snowflake session.

Comment: As I understand, you don't want to run many SQL scripts in one session. How does the above command will help on this? I think the issue is about external authentication, it's probably preventing "EOF to work" as snowsql is not expecting you to enter commands until authentication is done.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gokhan says this looks to be down to the authentication method. Authentication via a non-browser method makes the problem go away.